# Change class based on observable

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I have a field in my viewmodel called "Rotation". If it's 0, the image remains at 0 degrees (north). If it's 1, 90 degrees etc.

The obeservable is changing when I expect it to (on button click), but the style is not updating.

```
self.RotateLeft = function (data) {

    this.Rotation(this.Rotation + 1);
    if (this.Rotation() == 4)
        this.Rotation(0);
  //  alert(data.Rotation());

}
```

My image is defined as:

```
<img data-bind="attr: {src: Image}, css: {north: Rotation()==0, east: Rotation()==1, south: Rotation()==2, west: Rotation()==3}" alt="text: Description" class="img-responsive">
```

And my css:

```
.north {
transform:rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.west {
transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.south {
transform:rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */

}
.east {
transform:rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Is this the correct way to change the css class? If so, any idea why it's not rotating?

Comment: That seems fine to me.  How do you have the `RotateLeft()` function bound? Seems to me like you'd have issues since you're using `this` but not binding to `this`.  p.s., you don't necessarily have to use an object for the css binding, especially since the classes you want are all mutually exclusive, you could use an observable that returns the class name(s) that you want applied.

Comment: Thanks @JeffMercado - found my issue. See the javascript . .. . . the line "this.Rotation + 1". I forgot the brackets! :) It was adding 1 to a function. Changing it to this.Rotation() + 1 resolved the issue.

Comment: Ah, missed that one too! Glad it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Glad you got it working.  But considering the classes are all going to be mutually exclusive, you should probably bind to an observable with the classes you want to apply directly.  It will greatly simplify everything.

```js
var viewModel = {
  content: ko.observable('foobar'),
  css: ko.observable(),
  cssOptions: [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ],
  next: function () {
    var css = viewModel.css(),
        cssOptions = viewModel.cssOptions,
        length = cssOptions.length,
        index = cssOptions.indexOf(css),
        nextIndex = index >= 0 ? index + 1 : 0;
    viewModel.css(cssOptions[nextIndex % length]);
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('main'));
```

```css
.red   { color: red;   }
.green { color: green; }
.blue  { color: blue;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div data-bind="text: content, css: css"></div>
  <div>
    <select data-bind="value: css, options: cssOptions, optionsCaption: 'css'"></select>
    <button data-bind="click: next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Error found in javascript.

```
this.Rotation + 1
```

should be

```
this.Rotation() + 1
```

Rookie error.